# Debugging in javascript of google maps options

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cordova

I have this problem with my code, everytime it hits the following code: (im using cordova, so debugging is hard)

```
var mapoptions = {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        panControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        panControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
        },
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
        },
        scaleControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        streetViewControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
        }
    };
```

Anybody know why this could cause the javascript not to run? Made an alert before and after, only get the alert before..

My scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jqm/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="georescue.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you including the Google Maps API javascript file?  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

Comment: Im including it without a api key, it haven't been a problem before.

Comment: Could be I have to whitelist google.maps in cordova, just gonna try it..

Comment: Problem solved by whitelisting google.maps in cordova. Thanks.